# Editing a HTML/CSS theme, but can't seem to edit it correctly

Tags: html, css, themes

SOLVED*

I want the image to be hyperlinked. The text already is, however I can't seem to do the same for the image. It basically has the overlayed image and then the hyperlinked product title below it. I need it to redirect the image to the same link.

Here's the code: ------------------image--------------------------

```
<div class="block2"> 
    {% assign product_created_at = product.created_at | date: '%s' %}
    {% assign time_ago = 'now' | date: '%s' | minus: product_created_at | divided_by: 86400 %} 
    {% assign product_new_time = settings.product_new_time | times: 1 %} 

    <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative
        {% if time_ago < product_new_time %}block2-labelnew{% endif %}
        {% if on_sale %} block2-labelsale{% endif %}"> 
        <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
            <img class="" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: img_size }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

--------------------------------TEXT WORKING HYPERLINK-----------------------

```
<div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
    <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">
        {{ product.title }}
    </a>
    {% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}
        <span class="block2-oldprice m-text7 p-r-5"> {{ product.compare_at_price_max | money }} </span> <span class="block2-newprice m-text8 p-r-5"> {{ product.price | money }} </span>
    {% else %}
        <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5"> {{ product.price | money }} </span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

`

RESULTING HTML

```html
<!-- Block2 -->
<div class="block2">
  
  
  
  <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative  ">
    <a href="/products/boxy7-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve">
      <img class="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2672/5778/products/item-15_7ca55ba5-301e-4461-92ea-68c8b02e35e7_1200x1600.jpg?v=1515096104" alt="Boxy7 T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve">
    </a>
    <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4">
      <a href="/products/boxy7-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
        <!-- <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
      </a>
      <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-loading-text="Loading..." title="Add to Cart" onclick="cart.add('8772548722730', 'Boxy7 T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve');">
          Add to Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
    <a href="/products/boxy7-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">
      Boxy7 T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve
    </a>
    
    <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
      <span class=money>$20.00</span>
    </span>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Solis Ortus helped and this is the result:

```js
<div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative {% if time_ago < product_new_time %}block2-labelnew{% endif %} {% if on_sale %} block2-labelsale{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
      <img class="" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: img_size }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
    </a>
    <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4" onclick="location.href= '{{ product.url }}'" >
      <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
        <!-- <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
      </a>
      <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-loading-text="{{ 'products.product.loading' | t }}" title="{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.variants.first.id }}', '{{ product.title }}');">
          {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the CSS part where it created a fake cursor

```css
/* ------------------------------------ */
.block2-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the resulting HTML (from View Source in the browser)? Also, which framework is this?

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: I've copy / paste the result html <a> with the <img> and it was hyperlinked in my case :/.

Comment: Ehm... in your snippet, it seems to work. The image links to the same URL as the text below. So am I misunderstanding things, or is this just a quirk in the snippet here?

Comment: @MrLister this is Shopify

Comment: This is a similar theme(it will only work if you click on the product title, not image): https://fashe-theme.myshopify.com/collections/all

Comment: yeah, this works - your output html looks like it should be fine, and the snippet works

Comment: then why is it when I try it, it doesn't seem to work? Even through the website it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked example web shop does not work for me on Firefox because the dark semitransparent overlay div is in front of the link. When I hide the overlay it works for me (mouse pointer changes).

Proof of concept with inline style (only for demonstration). I've hidden the div with `display:none;`

```
<div class="block2">
  <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative  ">
    <a href="/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail">
      <img class="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2672/5778/products/item-03_1200x1600.jpg?v=1514269273" alt="Boxy T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve Detail">
    </a>
    <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4" style="display: none;">
      <a href="/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
        <!-- <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
      </a>
      <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-loading-text="Loading..." title="" onclick="cart.add('8250556252202', 'Boxy T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve Detail');" data-original-title="Add to Cart">
          Add to Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
    <a href="/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">
      Boxy T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve Detail
    </a>

    <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
      <span class="money" data-currency-usd="$20.00">$20.00</span>
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Please use a web browser debugger to check if in your example we have an overlay, too. If yes, it explains why the code snippet is working, because in the snippet there is no CSS.

---

Edit to answer comment:

Wrapping the div with an anchor tag, too, didn't work for me (maybe invalid HTML?). 
You could add a link to the div: Add an event via JavaScript or a dirty hack in the following code example: `onclick="location.href='/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail'"` on the hover element and fake mouse pointer with css.

```
<div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative  ">
    <a href="/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail">
      <img class="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2672/5778/products/item-03_1200x1600.jpg?v=1514269273" alt="Boxy T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve Detail">
    </a>
    <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4" onclick="location.href='/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail'" >
      <a href="/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
        <!-- <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
      </a>
      <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-loading-text="Loading..." title="" onclick="cart.add('8250556252202', 'Boxy T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve Detail');" data-original-title="Add to Cart">
          Add to Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

main.css on line 1739:

```
/* ------------------------------------ */
.block2-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

Edit: Answer to next comment on 2018-05-30:

Make sure the add-to-cart button is in front of the hover panel. Stop event bubbling.

```
<div class="block2">
  <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative  ">
    <a href="/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail">
      <img class="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2672/5778/products/item-03_1200x1600.jpg?v=1514269273" alt="Boxy T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve Detail">
    </a>
      <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4" onclick="location.href='https://fashe-theme.myshopify.com/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail'">
      <a href="/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
        <!-- <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
      </a>
      <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-loading-text="Loading..." title="" onclick="cart.add('8250556252202', 'Boxy T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve Detail');event.stopPropagation();" data-original-title="Add to Cart">
          Add to Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
    <a href="/products/boxy-t-shirt-with-roll-sleeve-detail" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">
      Boxy T-Shirt with Roll Sleeve Detail
    </a>

    <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
      <span class="money" data-currency-usd="$20.00">$20.00</span>
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

This means: We have to add the `event.stopPropagation();` in the `onclick` of the button.

Comment: Yes, it actually did make it work, however, when I remove it, the add to cart button vanished. Anyway I can still have it? Or if I can just move the overlay behind the link?

Comment: Hello, I had another problem and made a post for it. Please take a look.

Comment: Hello. I stumbled upon a problem with your solution. As it does enable the link for the product, it doesn’t allow the add to cart button to function and, instead, goes to the link. Is there anyway it can be do that the image itself is linked while the overlay is kept constant, with the add to cart left alone?

Comment: I would say you have to add the link to the hover of the 'add-to-cart-panel'.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer.